# Getline from stringstream to template variable

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map`-like class where I read variables and values from a text file, this piece of code parses each line, `str` is a line from the text file and it looks like this `VAR_NAME=value`, `out` is where value should go, it is a template variable.

```
[...]
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<str.substr(str.find("=")+1, str.length()-1);
T out;
ss>>out;
cmap[str.substr(0, str.find("="))] = out;
[...]
```

Now, with this code everything works fine, but i get some problem when I set `T` to `std::string`, if I have a line like this `VAR_NAME=value spaced`, at the end I get only `value`, `spaced` gets cut off as I use the `>>` operator, and I'm wondering how to make it work by leaving the code as clean as possible, I found getline, but it seems not to work for me...

Comment: You could make an overloaded wrapper function for the set of functions `stoi`, `stof`, etc, depending on T. The overload that converts to string should then just return back the argument.

Comment: @Banan I think that would be too much complicated, but it could be my last option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper class and its specialization.

```
template <typename T> struct ValueExtractor
{
   static T get(std::string const& s)
   {
      T out;
      std::stringstream ss(s);
      ss >> out;
      return out;
   }
};
```

And now a specialization for `std::string`.

```
template <> struct ValueExtractor<std::string>
{
   static std::string get(std::string const& s)
   {
      return s;
   }
};
```

And change your implementation to:

```
T out = ValueExtractor<T>::get(str.substr(str.find("=")+1));
```

Comment: That is so far the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is split your `key=val` string into a `std::string key` and a `T` val, the simplest way is to just use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
size_t eq = str.find('=');
std::string key = str.substr(0, eq);
T val = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str.substr(eq+1));
```

Comment: Any methods without using external libraries?

Comment: Yeah look at the code for lexical_cast and write your own.